# Как корректно отдать ответ после ajax-запроса?

Tags: ajax, django

Дело такое, что не могу отдать ответ от сервера к клиенту. Нужно вернуть словарь со значениями, но как это сделать? В коде выглядит примерно так:

```
response_dict = {'success': True, 'info': 'some text', 'errors': 'some errors'}
return HttpResponse(response_dict, mimetype = 'text/plain')
```

После ajax-запроса возвращается просто строка "successinfoerrors", т.е. строка из ключей словаря. Есть предположение, что неправильно указан mimetype. Может кто-нибудь откроет для меня завесу, как правильно вернуть нужные данные из вьюхи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю так:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def view(request):
    #Тут код вьюхи
    response_dict = {'success': True, 'info': 'some text', 'errors': 'some errors'}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                    mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 1):

В [django-annoying](https://github.com/soad241/django-annoying) есть декоратор ajax_request

```
@ajax_request
def my_view(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    news_titles = [entry.title for entry in news]
    return {'news_titles': news_titles}
```

там же есть класс JsonResponse, который можно использовать

```
from annoying.decorators import JsonResponse

def my_view(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    news_titles = [entry.title for entry in news]
    return JsonResponse({'news_titles': news_titles})
```